# x2go sesion on remote server freezes after certain amount of time

Tags: x2go

I got an issue with x2go on remote server. It seems that screen freezes. I can log in and work under ssh session but I got no response from x2go.
I did turned of screen saver and all power saving features but I still got freeze issue.
I am running latest Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Any update on this issue? Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same problem with x2go and Ubuntu 22.04. Tried xfce and lxde on the server, both have the same issue. I have disabled the compositor from settings under Window Manager Tweaks. It solved the sluggish and thick shadow border issue but not the freeze.

I somehow had two screensavers installed in xfce. Removing xscreensaver and disabling the screensaver did the trick for me.